# OpenCV inRange changes Mat type

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, bitwise-and

I can't get rid of this error in OpenCV:

> OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is
>   neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type),
>   nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array')

I found out with `Mat.type();` that all of my `Mat(img)` has type 16 but after function `inRange` my `img3` changed type to 0. Then I can't use function `bitwise_and` because it has not the same type.

How can I convert it to same type?

```
Mat img1 = imread(argv[1], 1);
Mat img2, img3, img4;

cvtColor(img1, img2, CV_BGR2HSV);
GaussianBlur(img2, img2, Size(15,15), 0); 
inRange(img2, Scalar(h_min_min,s_min_min,v_min_min), Scalar(h_max_min,s_max_min,v_max_min), img3); // now img3 changed type to 0
bitwise_and(img1, img3, img4); // img1.type()=16, img3.type()=0 ERROR
```

Comment: For all intents and purposes, `inRange` in OpenCV gives you a thresholded binary image. Of type `CV_8U`, if I'm not mistaken. Try converting it back to desired type using `img3.convertTo(img3, CV_16U)` or whatever you need.

Comment: thank you for quick respond but after img3.convertTo(img3, CV_16U) the type is 2, and after img3.convertTo(img3, 16) is type still 0

Comment: what do you want to achieve? setting all elements to zero that are not in the range? instead of bitwise_and try `img1.copyTo(img4,img3);` and try `imshow("img3", img3); cv::waitKey(0);` to test whether `inRange` gives the result you want to get.

Comment: about your previous comment: `img3.convertTo(img3, CV_16U)` only convertes the type, not the number of channels. what you need is CV_16UC3 but you can't get that with `.convertTo` and it wouldnt do what you expect. So if you really want to use `bitwise_and` on all 3 channels, you have to `cv::merge` a vector with 3 times 16U version of your img3...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal, as `inRange` returns a 1-channel mask (a value for each pixel), so to perform the bitwise operation simply transform the mask back to 3-channel image:

```
cvtColor(img3,img3,CV_GRAY2BGR);
bitwise_and(img1, img3, img4);// now both images are CV_8UC3 (=16)
```

EDIT: as Berak says, to change the number of channels you must use `cvtColor`, not `Mat::convertTo`. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you for quick respond but it didn't help. Type is still 0.        inRange(img2, Scalar(h_min_min,s_min_min,v_min_min), Scalar(h_max_min,s_max_min,v_max_min), img3);
    cout << "Image before convertTo: " << img3.type() << endl; //0
    img3.convertTo(img3, CV_8UC3);
    cout << "Image after convertTo: " << img3.type() << endl; //0

Comment: convertTo does not change the number of channels, only the depth. it needs cvtColor here instead.

Comment: Great, thanks. I used cvtColor(img3,img3,CV_GRAY2BGR,3); and it works :)